# Is there any task to copy files from TFS to a folder?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, task

**Scenario**: I need as part of my deploy scripts I have a task that copy files from a source to a origin.

Now I have to change the source. Instead of being a normal folder it has to be a location in my TFS.

Is there any task to do it? I can't find any.

I am trying to get the files manually from TFS using something similar to:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TF>"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe"</TF>
  <TFSourceLocation>$/TFSDIR</TFSourceLocation>
  <SolutionRoot>.</SolutionRoot>
  <RemoteWebRoot>$(DestinationRoot)\DIR</RemoteWebRoot>
  <Copy>xcopy /E /I /R /Y</Copy>
</PropertyGroup>

<Exec Command="$(TF) get $(TFSourceLocation) /force /recursive /version:T /noprompt" ContinueOnError="true" />
```

I don't have to compile anything. I only need to copy some files that now are stored in TFS to a folder.

**Question:** Is this the best approach? or exists a task that allows me to copy from TFS to a folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your question completely, but if you want to download some files from TFS to a folder on the build server, the command you are using is the best option.

Only be aware that you need a workspace configured so TFS knows where to download the files to.

Another option is to use the TF VIEW command:

```
tf view $/myitem /console /collection:http://mytfsserver:8080/tfs/defaultcollection >c:\localfile
```

This will show the contents of the item to the console and prints it to c:\localfile. You then get around the workspace issue.

Comment: Exactly this is what I am trying, but having problems setting up the Workspace... so I was wondering if maybe there was another way of doing it with a simple task...

Comment: Modified the answer to also have the tf view option